# echo/print starting from exact character

Tags: php, variables

I don't know if it's possible but i want to achieve this:

i have lot of product id's, each one being a different variable: `$p1, $p2, $p3,` etc.

I'm using that variable to call images and links, so that's quite simple (the images names are the same than product id).

The structure of the names are: `1234-123` . The first sequence can be 3 or 4 numbers lenght, and the second sequence can be 2 or 3 numbers lenght.

i.e:

`$p1 = '1234-123'`

`$p2 = '123-12'`

I need to display those products ids in a certain format: `Product($p1): 1234 (123)`

So, my concrete question is:

**How can i separate this 2 sequences? i mean, something like:**

```
PRODUCT: <?php echo from first value to "-"?> (<?php echo from "-" to end of variable value ?>)
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. Would you please explain more?

Comment: Paul, moonwave99 gave me an excelent answer already, that's what i was looking for. Thanks anyway to read my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
list($firstPart, $secondPart) = explode('-', $p1);
```

Comment: moonwave, you helped me a lot. I'll use this and see if i can resolve it from myself.